# Expression tree library and relations between enums

Tags: c#, .net, enums, expression-trees

In C# I can successfully compare enum values using any relational operators, like below:

```
var res  = SomeEnumType.First < SomeEnumType.Second
```

While trying to accomplish the same using expression library:

```
var arg1 = Expression.Constant(SomeEnumType.First);
var arg2 = Expression.Constant(SomeEnumType.Second);
var res  = Expression.LessThan(arg1, arg2);
```

the following error is thrown (analogically for <=, > and >=):

> The binary operator LessThan is not defined
>   for the types 'Prog.SomeEnumType' and 'Prog.SomeEnumType'.

What is the correct way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert enum value to the enum underlying type:

```
var arg1 = Expression.Constant(SomeEnumType.First);
var arg2 = Expression.Constant(SomeEnumType.Second);
var enumType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof (SomeEnumType));
var res = Expression.LessThan(Expression.Convert(arg1, enumType), Expression.Convert(arg2, enumType));
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what the C# compiler does with expressions that compare enums.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can just convert it to int (or whatever type your enum is based on) to achieve the required result.